# Wordpress problem in path with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

The problem is that it does not read the path placed in javascript to the photo directory.

```
prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><img src="http://page.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/po-poprawkach_25.png"></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><img src="http://page.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/po-poprawkach_25.png"></button>',
```

it's can't be read it i don't know why.
Devtools show failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Thanks

Comment: This problem was only in Wordpress without Wordpress it works fine.

Comment: The image does not seem to exist on the server. When I visit the URL in my browser I also get a 404 error. If it does exist it is probably a `.htaccess` related problem. Do you have any plugins installed that modify the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: page is in my company on network drive nobody wan't see this but i see. The problem is the javascript read old path in javascript i can't change it. If i paste img in main catalog wordpress it's be > "img/popoprawkach/..." its works but if i change path to "http://page.pl/wp-content/uploud/..." its still read old path mean "img/popoprawkach/..."

Comment: I don't think so i have only install Advanced Custom Fields,WPForms Lite and Slide Anything